# exit() and killProcess() doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm trying to close my app when back button is pressed. So I overridden onBackPressed() in my activity:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
}
```

I also tried:

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

my app got 3 tasks and 5 activities: A, B, C, D and E. Where I placed A, B and C in one task While D and E got their own tasks. I want to exit the app when the back button is pressed in activities A, D and E.

I try toasting from onBackPressed() and function callback works fine.

When I click the back button on my device in activities A or D or E it just goes to the previous activity from another task !!

Comment: Don't do this.  Invest some time in reading about the Activity Lifecycle and how Android apps actually work - it's a bit different from developing programs for other platforms, in particular the mapping between process and activity is not what you seem to think it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class CloseApplication 
{
private static  boolean isToCloseApp = false;
public static boolean isToCloseApp()
{
    return isToCloseApp;
}
public static void updateFlagToCloseTheApp(boolean flag)
{
    isToCloseApp = flag;
}
}
```

onBackKey Press UseCode

```
public void onBackPressed()
{
   CloseApplication.updateFlagToCloseTheApp(true);      
    finish();
}
```

One more Thing in each activity of your application Override the onResume method.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    if(CloseApplication.isToCloseApp())
    {
        finish();
    }
}
```

mark the answer solve if it solve your problem and so that it  helps the other to find the answer.